# If you remove left recursions & left factor a CNF grammer, does it remain a CNF?

Tags: compiler-construction, automata

If we remove only left recursions or only left factor, does the received grammar retain CNF form?

Comment: CNF is CNF; it's not dependent on the process by which the grammar was turned into CNF. If a grammar meets the requirements of CNF, it's CNF, regardless of who wrote nor where.

Comment: what I mean is you have a CNF. it has left recursions. You remove the left recursions from the CNF using a left recursion elimination algorithim and create an equivalent grammer. Does the received grammar have all the CNF properties?

Comment: i guess that depends on the details of your left-recursion eliminator, but probably not. Removing left recursion introduces ε-productions and productions of the form `A' -> a A`, neither of which are valid CNF.

Comment: I see, that makes sense for sure... How about left factoring?

Comment: Same. If you try it, you'll immediately see the problem.